# Google sheets submittal button to transfer rows of data to appropriate google sheet based off of column data

Tags: button, google-sheets, export

I need help creating a script for a submittal button to copy and export rows of data to their correct sheet based off of the column data entered. I have to track stocks and categorize them according to their Market Cap size. Therefor I have a google spreadsheet with 7 designated tabs separated for each market cap size category (<2B,2B-5B,5B-10B,10B-20B,20B-50B,50B-100B,100B+). The spreadsheet was running slow due to all of the active commands of =GoogleFinance and =importhtml, and will often update and change information that I didn't want changed so I have created a "Submit" tab for the purpose of speeding up my spreadsheet and the data entry process. This "submit" tab will be the only tab running active functions like =GoogleFinance and =importhtml. When I hit the submit button, I need the row (or rows) of data to copy the values only and not the formulas of each cell and transfer each row to their correct tab depending on the number in the Market Cap column. For Example, a company with a Market Cap size of 7,000,000,000 would be exported to auto populate the next row of the tabbed google sheet labeled "5B-10B".

I have attached a screenshot of my spreadsheet ([HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV4Gm.png)). It shows my "Submit" sheet with the submit and clear buttons, the columns and rows that would be used for data entry, as well as the 7 tabs for the sheets based off of Market Cap size. The Market Cap size is tracked in column #7 (column G). Each sheet for the designated Market Cap is outlined in the same format as the "submit" sheet. I have a script that works well for the "clear" button, but cannot find one that encompasses my needs for the "submit" button. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

This is the closest that I can get it but it still will not populate in the destination tab. I added a column #7 for Market Cap size category.

```
    function movingRows() {

var spreadsheetUrlToWatch = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOoQ6y6TDgQ4Rwn-xlAoU4b5RwHItV5t58HyKqT65Xs/edit#gid=2100951701'; //Submit sheet

var columnNumberToWatch = 7; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var valueToWatchA = "<2B";
var valueToWatchB = "2B-5B";
var valueToWatchC = "5B-10B";
var valueToWatchD = "10B-20B";
var valueToWatchE = "20B-50B";
var valueToWatchF = "50B-100B";
var valueToWatchG = "100B+";
var spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToA = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOoQ6y6TDgQ4Rwn-xlAoU4b5RwHItV5t58HyKqT65Xs/edit#gid=2043561231"; //<2B
var spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToB = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOoQ6y6TDgQ4Rwn-xlAoU4b5RwHItV5t58HyKqT65Xs/edit#gid=1162335222"; //2B-5B
var spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToC = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOoQ6y6TDgQ4Rwn-xlAoU4b5RwHItV5t58HyKqT65Xs/edit#gid=135695374"; //5B-10B
var spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToD = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOoQ6y6TDgQ4Rwn-xlAoU4b5RwHItV5t58HyKqT65Xs/edit#gid=439595584"; //10B-20B
var spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToE = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOoQ6y6TDgQ4Rwn-xlAoU4b5RwHItV5t58HyKqT65Xs/edit#gid=2048419386"; //20B-50B
var spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToF = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOoQ6y6TDgQ4Rwn-xlAoU4b5RwHItV5t58HyKqT65Xs/edit#gid=908834684"; //50B-100B
var spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToG = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jOoQ6y6TDgQ4Rwn-xlAoU4b5RwHItV5t58HyKqT65Xs/edit#gid=1122437169"; //100B+

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrlToWatch);
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
var sheetNameToWatch = ss.getSheets()[0].getSheetName();
console.log(sheetNameToWatch);

if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatchA) {

  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToA).getSheets()[0];
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
}
else if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatchB) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToB).getSheets()[0];
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
}
else if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatchC) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToC).getSheets()[0];
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
}
else if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatchD) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToD).getSheets()[0];
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
}
else if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatchE) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToE).getSheets()[0];
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
}
else if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatchF) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToF).getSheets()[0];
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
}
else if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatchG) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrlToMoveTheRowToG).getSheets()[0];
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);
}
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a simple if/else statement? Check out https://www.jacorre.com/tutorial/google-spreadsheet-values-formulas/ to find out how to get the values from a certain range

Comment: Thanks Da Mahdi03! But even then I am still running into issues.

Comment: Is the target range the correct one? Are you receiving any errors along with your execution? @Golden

Comment: Hey Ale13, I've been playing around with the target range but I can't find where the values are going, if they're being sent at all. No errors pop up during execution either.

Comment: Can you check the "Executions" tab as well?